# Is it possible to use a VariableResolver inside an Action?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, el

### Overview

I have a properties file which as loaded on a listener and contains some EL expressions on two variables:

```
foo.path=${pageContext.request.contextPath}/foo
bar.path=${application.realPath}/bar
```

I was able to load this properties and resolve the EL expressions on the JSP pages they are used, but there are one action I need to resolve those too.
I can't put those properties on the Action because the app was customized to allow those properties to be overrided by providing a properties file in a folder the system knows.

### What I have done so far

**1. Evaluator class to parse the properties**

```
public class MyExpressionEvaluator
{
  private PageContext pageContext;

  public MyExpressionEvaluator(PageContext pageContext)
  {
    this.pageContext = pageContext;
  }

  public <T extends Object> T evaluate(String expression, Class<T> clazz)
  {
    T value = null;

    ExpressionEvaluator evaluator = pageContext.getExpressionEvaluator();
    VariableResolver variableResolver = pageContext.getVariableResolver();
    try
    {
      value = clazz.cast(evaluator.evaluate(expression, clazz,
          variableResolver, null));
    }
    catch (ELException e)
    {
      log.error("Error while evaluating expression", e);
    }

    return value;
  }
}
```

**2. Call the functions on a jsp scriptlet:**

```
private String buildConfigObject(Configuration conf, PageContext pageContext) {
        // Helper function which retrieves a JSON from properties
        StringBuilder configValue = parseConfig(conf);

        MyExpressionEvaluator evaluator = new MyExpressionEvaluator(pageContext);
        value = evaluator.evaluate(configValue.toString(), String.class);

        return (value != null) ? value : configValue.toString();
}

<script type="text/javascript">
 var generatedContent = <%= buildConfigObject(conf, pageContext)%>;
</script>
```

---

I don't know how to proceed with the Action, since I don't have access to the pageContext on that point.

### Versions

- JSP: 2.0
- Servlet API: 3.0
- JSTL: 1.2.0
- Struts: 2.1.6

Comment: Consider moving to EL 3.0 (Servlet 3.1, e.g. Tomcat 8 etc), would make a lot of things easier.

Comment: Indeed! It would solve lot of my problems, but would take longer time than the one I have. So, this is not the best solution right now.

Comment: @AuroPimentel You have access to the request, though.

Comment: And how can I create a expression evaluator from that?